# How to visualize a graph/network in 3D

Tags: graph, 3d, graph-visualization

I am working with networks which vertices are nodes of brain areas with specific coordinates.

I need to visualize these networks in a 3D enviroments in order to improve the understanding of my results.

Up to now I have tried to plot them using `rglplot` of `igraph library` in R, but the result is not so good in truth.
Currently I am plotting them using projection on each pair of axis (XY, XZ, YZ).

Futhermore I also have tried several tools like `gephi`, but it seems that 3D is not really supported.

There is some tool or software for visualizing a network in a 3D space?

Comment: What do you mean by *"using projection on each pair of axis (XY, XZ, YZ)"*. Anyway I know [Ubigraph](http://ubietylab.net/ubigraph/) can do it and also [NAViGaTOR](http://ophid.utoronto.ca/navigator/index.html)

Comment: I did mean that I plotted in 2d on each pair of dimension. Thank you for your advices about the tools.

Comment: I remembered how it works for Gephi, see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that in fact Gephi supports 3d display of graphs, only to see the effect you have to pan the graph in the Overview Pane by keeping you mouse's scroll wheel pressed! Also the rotation options are limited to rotating on the x-axis

See the example below for the `Les Miserables` graph laid out with the Force Atlas 3d algorithm

[image]

You can also set the coordinates from within the Data Laboratory with the aid of the `Data laboratory helper` plugin. See a screenshot below

[image]

Comment: Are you able to use your set of vertices coordinates for visualizing the graph?  Because I can't get how to do it.

Comment: Yes I am! You can actually use the "Data Laboratory helper" plugin and it will allow you to recast one of your columns to x-, y-, z- coordinates, see the discussion here: https://forum.gephi.org/viewtopic.php?t=1811

Comment: It seems that you can set X and Y only, instead I have to set also the Z.

Comment: Actually it is possible to set the z-coordinate too by selecting `Set standard column`, see the screenshot in the edited post